# Quicksort - CLRS implementation in python

Tags: python, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to implement quick sort in python. The [CLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) algo version.

Here is what i have written. I think it is working fine for the most part except for the middle elements of the list.

Can someone help?

```
#! /usr/bin/python

#quick sort

def swap(array,i,j):
    temp = array[i]
    array[i] = array[j]
    array[j] = temp

def partition(array, start,end):
    x = array[end]
    i = start -1
    for j in xrange(start+1, end):
        if (array[j] <= x):
            i = i+1
            swap (array,i,j)
        swap(array,i+1,end)
    return i+1

def quicksort(array,p,r):
    if p<r:
        q = partition(array,p,r)
        quicksort(array,p,q-1)
        quicksort(array,q+1,r)

def main():
    unsortedArray = [2,8,7,1,3,5,6,4,9,0]
    quicksort(unsortedArray,0,len(unsortedArray)-1)
    print unsortedArray


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output should be `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`.Instead it is printing `[2, 0, 3, 4, 1, 6, 5, 7, 9, 8]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the pseudocode I found on https://users.cs.fiu.edu/~giri/teach/5407/F08/Lec7.pdf,
your implementation of `partition` is wrong, because

```
swap(array,i+1,end)
```

should **NOT** be carried out in every iteration, but instead only once in the function.

I rewrote it like this:

```
def partition(array, start,end):
    x = array[end]
    i = start -1
    for j in xrange(start, end):
        if (array[j] <= x):
            i = i+1
            swap (array,i,j)
    swap(array,i+1, end)
    return i+1
```

and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Made partition() simpler and Pythonic.

- swap() is not needed.
- use enumerate() to access an element in a list

```py
def partition(A, p, r):
    pivot = A[r]
    i = -1
    for j, n in enumerate(A):
        if A[j] <= pivot:
            i += 1
            A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
    return i
```